# Can 2D and 3D transforms be applied to iOS controls?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, 3d, 2d

Having never actually developed with iOS before, I am investigating the possibilies with standard iOS controls such as text fields, list etc. and would like to know which transforms can be applied to them.

Do these standard controls support 2D transforms such as scale, translate and rotate?
Do these standard controls also support 3D transforms such as scale, translate and rotate which include a z axis?

If the answer is yes to either questions, what "level" of support exists?  For example with a text field, if I transform it in 3D coordinate space can I still enter text into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and a lot. UITextField for example inherits from UIControl with inherits from UIView. This means that you have access to the view's transform property directly via its transform property:

```
[myTextField setTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(a, b, c, d, x, y)];
```

Or for 3D support, you can access the transform property of the view's layer to apply a CATransform3D:

```
[myTextField.layer setTransform:CATransform3DRotate(trans, theta, x, y, z)];
```

CATransform3D is defined as follows, and as @Xman pointed out, you'll need to import the QuartzCore framework using `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, as well as link against it in your build phases.

```
struct CATransform3D
{
    CGFloat m11, m12, m13, m14;
    CGFloat m21, m22, m23, m24;
    CGFloat m31, m32, m33, m34;
    CGFloat m41, m42, m43, m44;
};
typedef struct CATransform3D CATransform3D;
```

In both of these cases, you can still interact with the text field after a transform has been applied to it.

More information can be found in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW1).

Comment: OK, just to be clear, is it still possible to enter text even after a text field has been transformed in 3D coordinates so that it appears on the face of a cube for example?

Comment: Added a link to relevant documentation so people can read more

Comment: @FelixBembrick Sorry for the late response, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

Check `CATransform3D` also,

```
CATransform3D yourTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
yourTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;

//You can rotate the component in any angle around x,y,z axis using following line.
//Below line will rotate the component in 60 degree around y-axis.
yourTransform = CATransform3DRotate(yourTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);      //#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(d) (d * M_PI / 180)

//You can even translate the component along x,y,z axis
//Below line will translate component by 50 on y-axis
yourTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(yourTransform, 0, 50, 0);

//apply transform to component
yourComponent.layer.transform = yourTransform;
```

Don't forget to import

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**Hope this will help you.**